Is the layout-parser of Google Cloud Document AI capable of returning coordinates of blocks and text lines?
We are using Google Cloud Document AI layout parser to extract information from PDF documents. Now we would like to visualize the results and show what blocks it identified.
The blocks contain block_id, text_block and page_span attributes, but no information about coordinates of blocks.
Furthermore we would also be interested in having information about each text line specifically. In the documentation in the overview of the processing response we would expect to get page and line objects in the returned document object. Yet in the document object that was returned pages attribute is an empty list. Is this a configuration problem or is layout parser not capable of returning the information in question?
